# Strange issue with loading image from imageview

Tags: android, imageview, image-loading

I am using Glide in my app to load images from the server. The images are displayed in ViewPager. I am facing a strange issue. When image is loaded for the first time, it is displayed as follows:
[image]

But when I scroll pages and return to the original one it displays properly. 
[image]

I am not getting why is it happening.
I have set the view pager height to 140dp. The xml for viewpager adapter is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_banner"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="centerInside"
android:background="@drawable/car_bg"
tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Code to load image from url:

```
Glide.with(ctx).load(banner.getImgScrollBanner()).placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner).error(R.drawable.car_bg).into(bannerView);
```

Comment: try scaleType  not sure.

Comment: Try removing `android:scaleType="centerInside"` and add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` once,

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Tried still facing same problem

Comment: @Nitish see [here](http://etcodehome.blogspot.hu/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html), you might find helpful.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna If I try fitXY in scale type then its working fine.

Comment: @Nitish Then why don't you use that ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Earlier I was using fitXY only but on some screens it looked stretched while on some it looked compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `scaleType` on the `Glide` options:

**v3:**

```
Glide.with(ctx).load(banner.getImgScrollBanner()).centerInside().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner).error(R.drawable.car_bg).into(bannerView);
```

**v4:**

```
Glide.with(ctx)
     .apply(new RequestOptions()
              .centerCrop()
              .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
              .error(R.drawable.car_bg))
     .load(banner.getImgScrollBanner())
     .into(bannerView);
```